# how to take backup log file before its overwritten by other log file?

Tags: logging

I have two log files: *abc.log* and *abc.log_old*. When *abc.log* is full, it will override into *abc.log_old* files. But I am not sure when it will be full and the size of log file is not fixed. The log file is from a different system.

My requirement is to take the backup of *abc.log_old* file, before it's overwritten by *abc.log* file. How can take the backup log file before it's overwritten by other log file?

Comment: What operating system is this running on? There is `logrotate` for Unix/Linux.

Comment: @mrblewog perl  or python script to run on Linux Os

Comment: Ok, so it's running as a script. Worth clarifying the question on what's running, how it's being run, OS, and other details.

Comment: for the above requirement , i need a perl or shell script to perform above mentioned task. please provide a perl/shell script , to run on linux. , as i am new to perl/shell

Comment: Typically when you need something special to you and you can't do it yourself, you hire someone who can do it. When I see these sorts of requests, I tend to think that someone has committed to fulfilling a client requirement and hopes to abuse the good nature of the internet to get it done. Or, they are doing homework.

Comment: Re "*please provide a perl/shell script*", StackOverfow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel. This is a job for [`logrotate`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-logfiles-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Comment: i need script for this , no need to any tools

Comment: @jyotikumari: Please explain why you have that restriction? `logrotate` does exactly what you want (and a lot more besides). It is pre-installed on pretty much any Linux system and can easily be installed on just about anything else. You would need a very good reason to ignore it.

Comment: I have a feeling that the task is to copy a remote file before it is rotated.

Answer (score 2):

It would be far better if the application that overwrites `abc.log_old` would be the one backing it up. This is how systems are commonly setup. Specifically,

1. If it's time to reset `abc.log`,

   1. Backup `abc.log_old`.
   2. Rename `abc.log` to `abc.log_old`.
   3. Restart the service that's writing to `abc.log` to ensure that all file handles to the file now known as `abc.log_old` are closed.

Or on a system where you can't rename open files (e.g. Windows):

1. If it's time to reset `abc.log`,

   1. Stop the service that's writing to `abc.log`.
   2. Backup `abc.log_old`.
   3. Rename `abc.log` to `abc.log_old`.
   4. Restart the service that's writing to `abc.log`.

This is the idea behind [`logrotate`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-logfiles-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-16-04).

---

But it sounds like you want the backups to be performed by a system that's independent of the one overwriting `abc.log_old`.

Say it never takes less than T seconds for `abc.log` to get full. Run a script every T/3 seconds which does the following:

1. If `abc.log_old` exists,

   1. Backup `abc.log_old`.
   2. If the backup was successful,

      1. Delete `abc.log_old`.

or

1. If `abc.log_old` exists,

   1. If either its modification time or size is different than the last recorded numbers,

      1. Backup `abc.log_old`.
      2. If the backup was successful,

         1. Record `abc.log_old`'s modification time and size.

By using a period of T/3 seconds, there will be at least two attempts to backup the file before it gets overwritten (allowing one of the attempts to fail without issue). Use a period less than T/(N+1) to guarantee N attempts.

---

The above assumes the time needed to backup is less than the period. It also means repeated failures to backup will result in data loss. Both of these problem can be solved as follows:

1. If `abc.log_old` exists,

   1. If there are any files in a directory set aside to be the queue directory,

      1. Get the number of the highest numbered file in that directory.
   2. Else,

      1. Consider the highest numbered file to be `0`.
   3. Rename `abc.log_old` such that:

      - It will be moved into the queue directory.
      - It's file name ends with a number one higher than the previously obtained number.
2. Get the list of files in the queue directory.
3. Sort them numerically.
4. For each file in the list,

   1. Backup the file.
   2. If the backup was successful,

      1. Delete `abc.log_old`.
   3. Else,

      1. Exit.